# Can't create mongo db user within gitlab pipeline

Tags: mongodb, gitlab-ci

I'm writing gitlab pipeline which has to dynamically create new user for newly created application environment. Tho it looks super trivial I'm getting following error:

```
uncaught exception: SyntaxError: unexpected token: identifier :
```

from following file:

```
// createUser.js
use admin
db.createUser(
    {
        user: "test",
        pwd: "test",
        roles: [
            {
                role: "readWrite",
                db: "some-123123123-db-name"
            }
        ]
    }
)
```

which is used in pipeline like that

```
new user setup:
    image: mongo:4.2.6
    ...
    script:
        - mongo --host ${MONGO_HOST} --username ${MONGO_ADMIN_USERNAME} --password ${MONGO_ADMIN_PASSWORD} --authenticationDatabase admin createReviewUser.js
```

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check out the docs on [writing scripts for the mongo shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/) you will see that instead of using `use` to get a database you do:

```
conn = new Mongo();
db = conn.getDB("myDatabase");
```

There is lots of other good info in there. Check it our before converting what you use
a the `mongo` prompt into a script.

Comment: Cool, thanks but this way i have to provide once again connection details within js file like that `conn = new Mongo(mongohost_and_stuff)`, right?

Comment: Yes, you will need to input the arguments. For the `new Mongo` command.

Comment: Ok, but isn't there other way around it? I mean, I've already provided connection details in `mongo` cmd itself.

Comment: The new `Mongo` object you create creates a new client object that has only the default settings.